What is a sufficient condition for the ellipsoid E1(c1,P1) to belong to the ellipsoid E2(c2,P2)?
Given the center and shape matrix of the two ellipsoids,how do I know that ellipsoid E1 is inside ellipsoid E2?Judging by the center and shape matrix.Hopefully, I can prove it mathematically.
Such as the distance between the two centers, and the axis length of the ellipsoid.

E1 center is inside E2, volume of E2 >= E1, and the E1 and E2 surfaces don't intersect.  You'd have to solve the equation for the last one.

@ Matt Timmermans In fact, it is also possible if two ellipsoids are internally tangent. In short, the last problem is really difficult to solve.
